# Postgresql: How to repeat query as soon as finished?

Tags: postgresql, repeat

Let's say I have a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.Category = 'liquid' ORDER BY a.MeasurementTime DESC;
```

and I want to see the results coming into the database 'live'.

How can I write a query for Postresql which will repeat as soon as the query finishes?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the \watch n command in the terminal to re-execute the query every n seconds.

Example:

```
postgre=# SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION
postgre=# \watch 5
-- now the "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION" is re-executed every 5 seconds
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using the terminal? I want to do it purely via query. I want to do this just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: This is very nice because it is inside the psql shell (no reconnects needed). I will post a solution from terminal @pookie

Comment: Wow, Postgres never ceases to amaze me. thanks ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

You can't see them 'live'. Queries complete before returning to calling environment.

You could wrap this in a cron job ( depending on your environment ) or similar scheduler and have them run every minute, or a function and add that to pgagent to be run every minute.

To have a dml statement constantly running is not really a good idea and i would not recommend it for performance and table management purposes.

however...

Within a function you can create a loop with a wait clause using pg_sleep and just no break clause, but really a job is the best way to go.

Comment: Is there some postgresl function which I can make execute every `n` seconds? I do not want to use a cron job or some external code to execute the query. I am viewing the data in the IntelliJ database viewer.

Answer (score 1):

`watch -n1 'psql -h {ip} {db} {user} -c "select * from condition;"'`

Make sure that you set the password of the `{user}` inside an environment variable:

Linux> `export PGPASSWORD="password"`